# Can't install npm - Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages?

Tags: apt, 16.10, nodejs, npm

I am trying to upgrade my nodejs to 7.6 but failed. Now I have a new problem after re-installing node 6.10:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'npm' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.8.0-40 linux-headers-4.8.0-40-generic linux-image-4.8.0-40-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-40-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  nodejs*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 53 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 51.7 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 278133 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nodejs (6.9.5-1nodesource1~yakkety1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
(Reading database ... 274476 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nodejs (6.9.5-1nodesource1~yakkety1) ...
Purging configuration files for nodejs (6.9.5-1nodesource1~yakkety1) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing nodejs, directory '/usr/lib/node_modules' not empty so not removed
```

Why does it say `Package 'npm' is not installed, so not removed`? i have been using npm to install many node packages for my projects!!

I ignore the error and went on installing node 7.6:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.6 | sudo -E bash - 
bash: line 1: html: No such file or directory
bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
'ash: line 2: `<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
```

So I fell back to node 6.x. But I cannot install npm anymore:

```
$ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The nodesource nodejs includes npm so there is no need to install it separately.

Answer (score 63):

I  had the same issue with npm.

I suggest you install aptitude which can help you resolve conflicts

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

then install your package with aptitude

```
sudo aptitude install npm
```

Answer (score 62):

I had the same issue with npm and had to install the following packages in order:

```
sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev
sudo apt install nodejs-dev
sudo apt install node-gyp
sudo apt install npm
```

Hope this helps

Comment: (On Kubuntu 18.04) I had previously installed libssl-dev, which turns out to correspond to libssl1.1, but npm apparently requires 1.0. I had to remove libssl-dev and replace it with libssl1.0-dev, and everything then worked fine. The apt errors were not useful in determining what was wrong, so your answer was a life-saver.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* ~/.npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*

sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then install node and npm

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude install libnode-dev                        
sudo aptitude install libnode64
sudo aptitude install node-gyp
sudo aptitude install npm
```

Answer (score 1):

You **do not need to install `npm`** when installing `nodejs` from nodesource, as it **already includes** `npm`.

The error you're getting is because the `npm` package is tied to the built-in `nodejs` package.

Just do this:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

It will install both `node` and `npm`.

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Comment: installs `node`, but does not install `npm`.